# Работа Edit в процедуре Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

В стандартной процедуре procedure **TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);** - **Edit2** (прописываю) без проблем работает.

**Вопрос:** Почему в такой процедуре **procedure ScanDir(path : string);** - **Edit2** - **Вот такая ошибка:** Incompatible types: 'string' and 'Text'

```
procedure ScanDir(path: string);
var
  sr: TSearchRec;
  FileAttrs: Integer;
  s: tstringlist;
  Edit2: Tedit;

begin
  path := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(path);
  if FindFirst(path + '*.txt*', faAnyFile, sr) = 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      if (sr.Name <> '.') and (sr.Name <> '..') then
        if (sr.Attr and faDirectory) = faDirectory then
        begin
          Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Путь к обработанному файлу: ' + path +
            sr.Name);
          ScanDir(path + sr.Name);
        end
        else
        begin
          s := tstringlist.create;
          s.LoadFromFile(path + sr.Name);
          s.text := StringReplace(s.text, Form1.Memo2.Lines[0],
            Form1.Memo3.Lines[0], [rfreplaceall]);
          s.text := StringReplace(s.text, Form1.Memo2.Lines[1],
            Form1.Memo3.Lines[1], [rfreplaceall]);
          s.SaveToFile(path + Edit2.text + sr.Name); ////////Вот тут
          FreeAndNil(s);
        end;
    until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
    FindClose(sr);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ScanDir(Edit1.text + '\');
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Хм, странная ошибка - с учетом кода в вопросе.*

Потому что процедура `ScanDir` не является методом формы с контролом `Edit2`. Вам нужно обращаться к контролу с указанием того, на какой форме он находится:

```
s.SaveToFile(path + Form1.Edit2.text + sr.Name);
```

или передавать его в процедуру как парамeтр:

```
procedure ScanDir(path: string, Edit2: TEdit);
```

или лучше:

```
procedure ScanDir(path: string, editText: string);
...
  s.SaveToFile(path + editText + sr.Name);
```

Соответственно, строка

```
Edit2: Tedit;
```

в `var` не нужна.

Answer (score 2):

Вместо `Edit2.text` напишите `Form1.Edit2.text`.

Поскольку ваша функция не входит в класс, полем которого является `Edit2`, вам нужно использовать полную запись для доступа к компоненту.